# WoCommerce is not adding delivery charges during final payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal

i am using WoCommerce. this is my final checkout page

[image]

but when i process for payments. i am getting seeing $27 not $37..

Any idea, if i am missing something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your product requires shipping or not? If you open the product in the backend and check that it requires shipping.

Answer (score 0):

In backend check your product ...in the particular product check your shipping is enabled or not... if you enable the shipping...it will be work..